# Using more than one thread with vCPU in GAMS

Tags: cplex, vcpu

I am using GAMS to solve a linear problem with CPLEX.

As the needed memory is to high for my private machine, I set up a virtual server with the following specifications:

```
64GB RAM and 8vCPU
```

On my private machine (16GB RAM,  3.30 GHz with 12 logical processors) I normally use the following settings, to enable parallel calculation and speed up the whole process **a lot**, supposedly because I can use all of my CPU.

```
option LP=CPLEX;
option threads = 12;
```

When I am using this setting (threads = 8) on the virtual server, the CPU stays around 50% usage and the task takes forever.
Is it possible, that the "option threads" cannot be used for **virtual** CPUs?
What could be a workaround?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: There are lots of unknowns here, the most important being what kind of virtualization is applied and how cpu-limits are enforced (e.g. OS-based virt + CFS cpu-limits). Also how you measure cpu-usage (usually not a good indicator) and how this measurement interferes with virtualization.  As multithreading in general has less impact that people expect, i'm also wondering if your *speed up the whole process a lot* has a different cause (although it sounds that you are in control of software and can make sure the same versions are used). All in all... difficult to answer.